# code in Python movement is not smooth using sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wrote a function that will move a rectangle right and left to the edges in a loop.
I expected it to move in a constant speed. What actually happens is the movement is rough. 
The movement will change its speed.
How can I make it move in a constant speed ?

```
def btn_start_press():
    global x1, x2, y1, y2, canvas_width

    size = int(entry_size.get())
    x2 = x1 + size
    y2 = y1 + size
    label_size["text"] = size * 2

    forward = True
    while True:
        if forward:
            x1 += 1
            x2 += 1
        else:
            x1 -= 1
            x2 -= 1
        if x2 + size >= canvas_width:
            forward = False
        elif x1 <= 0 :
            forward = True

        time.sleep(0.005)
        canvas.coords(rect,x1,y1,x2,y2)
        canvas.update()
```

Comment: Due to limitation in scheduling and how it implemented the time `sleep()` is sleeping is not guaranteed. It might be longer and on older Python version even shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your computer outside of your code, meaning that your code isn't the only thing competing for resources. In your case this ends up being the case where the loop doesn't take the same amount of time each iteration and thus, ending up as a jagged movement. In your case the sleep time is also so low that it'll take up a lot of time allotted to your application.

The naive fix which probably will work fine in this case is to instead use the elapsed time between two redraws, and use that calculate how far to move the button.

If you go with `time.sleep(0.015)` your application will try to run its code at around 75 fps (subtracting the time spent in your code). You can use `time.time()` to get the current time (with milliseconds). Be aware that this time information can be rather coarse, and has other issues (such as changing if the computer's clock is adjusted). There [are better timers available](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html), but for this use case it should be good enough.

```
pixels_per_second = 100
previous_time = time.time()

while True:
    new_time = time.time()
    elapsed = new_time - previous_time
    pixels = pixels_per_second * elapsed

    if forward:
        x1 += pixels
        x2 += pixels
    else:
        x1 -= pixels
        x2 -= pixels

    if x2 + size >= canvas_width:
        forward = False
    elif x1 <= 0 :
        forward = True

    previous_time = new_time

    canvas.coords(rect,x1,y1,x2,y2)
    canvas.update()

    time.sleep(0.015)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but the speed accelerates exponentially.
added this line:  previous_time = new_time

Comment: Did you forget to include `previous_time = new_time` ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess it is not the timing but the visualization which is not smooth. Have you tried to print out the steps without visualization?

your are trying to update your  canvas 200 times per second.  That seems to much. We see a smooth motion with 25 - 60 fps.

update:

> I do need the movement to be this fast, and even faster. Is there a way to represent movement in a different way, other than updating the canvas so many times ?

You can still change your values that fast but if the eye can't see any difference there is no need for such a high frequent visual update. What you could try is to update the frame each 10th step.

But much better would be to run your calculation and the visualization async because what you probably want is a fixed time between your steps no matter how long the visualization takes.

Comment: I do need the movement to be this fast, and even faster.
Is there a way to represent movement in a different way, other than updating the canvas so many times ?

Comment: Updating a display at 200 Hz is not too much at all in modern times.

Comment: @Acorn Depending on use case, of course. For GUI applications there is absolutely no need to update the ui with 200hz, while for a game it can make sense.

Comment: I doubt to see any difference between 60 and 200 Hz but I guess that's another discussion.  Let's agree on that we're not talking about high-end video games or movies :)

Comment: @MatsLindh No, I am talking about displays, not about whether it is useful or not to update the backbuffer/canvas/whatever for a given application.

Comment: @Raphael If you are human, you do notice the difference :-) We don't know whether OP is trying to make a game, a movie, or anything else.

Comment: @Acorn: Well you are right in a way that I made some assumptions about how likely it is that we're talking about the bleeding edge of game development ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, just playing about with Python to better understand it :)

Comment: @Raphael Refreshing a display at more than 60 Hz is not bleeding edge, and not restricted to games either. That was half of my point.